# Embed readme in mainpage (doxygen)

Tags: c++, doxygen

Is there a way to embed a plain-text file (README.txt) into a mainpage for doxygen? (I'm maing it with cmake, so I could dump the variable but I'd think this type of thing would be built in).

Comment: @rwong -- It's probably the `\verbinclude` command that MadScienceDreams wants. `\include` is for files written in Doxygen's markdown language (very similar to the mark down used here). `\verbinclude` treats the included file as plain text, which is how READMEs are typically written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. In your mainpage.dox (or whatever you call it), place a link to your README.txt as a separate doxygen page.

```
\mainpage FooBar

...
\section other_docs Additional Documentation`

...
Key features that distinguish the current release, build instructions,
and a history of Project FooBar are described in the
\ref README "Foobar README file".
```

and then later on, generate that page by making your README.txt a plain text page file.

```
\page README README
\verbinclude README.txt
```